# how to get the coefficients out of the polynomal expression?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

At the input I get a polynomial as a string, 
I want to get its coefficients in variables, but i have no idea gow do this.
example:`7x^4+3x^3-6x^2+x-8`.Maximum degree is not known, coefficients are integers.
I will be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Can any coefficients be negative?

Comment: is the polynomial expression already simplified (e.g. can you have `x+x`)? How many variables can you have?

Answer (score 0):

Split by plus and minus (e.g. with [re.split](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.split)), preserving the signs in the results. Then for each substring, split by "x" to get the leading coefficient (+1 and -1 are special cases), and take note of missing powers of x (i.e. coefficient 0).